How to improve AWS Lambda Docker image logging layout when running locally
All the Docker builds I've created log outputs into the Docker UI just fine, they look like:
2024-04-15T23:42:40.362Z    6bbe7310-26ad-4333-92f3-409cd5c4c7e6    INFO    Event email has... 1 attachments
2024-04-15T23:42:40.366Z    6bbe7310-26ad-4333-92f3-409cd5c4c7e6    INFO    Email attachment has contentType... application/pdf.
2024-04-15T23:42:40.366Z    6bbe7310-26ad-4333-92f3-409cd5c4c7e6    INFO    Initiating new processor
2024-04-15T23:42:40.367Z    6bbe7310-26ad-4333-92f3-409cd5c4c7e6    INFO    http://172.18.0.7/api/v1/endpoint
2024-04-15T23:42:40.367Z    6bbe7310-26ad-4333-92f3-409cd5c4c7e6    INFO    Timeout - 0
2024-04-15T23:42:41.412Z    6bbe7310-26ad-4333-92f3-409cd5c4c7e6    INFO    No model information data returned... status - undefined

However, when I use any of the Amazon ECR repos to mock an AWS Lambda endpoint, e.g. FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12, I end up with logs that write on top of themselves in a single line. I assume this comes from the fact that the lambdas log to AWS cloudwatch which can have dictionary-like structure, I just can't figure out how to unwind that locally so that it is readable.
In the below, the warning log gets overwritten by a different log at tempora.   not_used,....

18 Apr 2024 17:02:46,153 [INFO] (rapid) INIT RTDONE(status: success)
18 Apr 2024 17:02:46,153 [INFO] (rapid) INIT REPORT(durationMs: 248.640000)
18 Apr 2024 17:02:46,154 [INFO] (rapid) INVOKE START(requestId: 940033f1-496e-4425-b98b-a7138e11b6eb)
AWS LAMBDA FUNCTION NAME: test_function
LAMBDA_WARNING: Unhandled exception. The most likely cause is an issue in the function code. However, in rare cases, a Lambda runtime update can cause unexpected function behavior. For functions using managed runtimes, runtime updates can be triggered by a function change, or can be applied automatically. To determine if the runtime has been updated, check the runtime version in the INIT_START log entry. If this error correlates with a change in the runtime version, you may be able to mitigate this error by tempora    not_used, config.ENVI, config.CUSTOMER = aws_lambda_function_name.lower().split('_')s.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html
18 Apr 2024 17:02:46,167 [INFO] (rapid) INVOKE RTDONE(status: success, produced bytes: 0, duration: 12.967000ms)


I've run multiple Docker containers with this image and attempted to update logging styles but to no avail
